# Unity how to reset score after scene change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I get my game over the scene the score still remains when a start a new game:

ScoringSYstem.cs

```
    public GameObject scoreText;

    public static int theScore;

    void Update()
    {   
        scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Score: " + theScore; 
    }
```

Timer.cs

```
   public string LevelToLoad;
 public static float timer1 = 30f;
 private Text timerSeconds;

    public GameObject scoreText;

    public static int theScore;


 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
 {
  timerSeconds = GetComponent<Text> ();
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () 
 {
  timer1 -= Time.deltaTime;
  timerSeconds.text = timer1.ToString("f0");
  if (timer1 <= 0) 
     {    
        timer1 = 30f;    
        Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad); 

 }
}
```

How does it in order to reset the score whenever a scene changes?

Comment: Why is  `theScore` static? What happens if you make it non-static by removing the `static` keyword?

Comment: I have a part that resets when ever i do a action, however i don't want to reset the timer

Comment: i actually get these erros if i remove the static https://prnt.sc/t7jswt

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add more of your code to the question to provide a reader with more context.

Comment: scoring system.cs  :  https://prnt.sc/t7jv9l  and timer.cs  : https://prnt.sc/t7jvi4

Comment: It is more helpful if the code can be seen in the question instead of having to follow links.

Comment: And make sure the indentation is correct to make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create an empty GameObject that you call GameManager then you add a Script to it that you call GameManager as well. So that you can acces your Score from everywhere.

```
public int score = 0;
public static int time = 30;   

#region Singelton
public static GameManager instance;

void Awake()
{
   if (instance != null)
   {
      Debug.LogWarning("More than one Instance of Inventory found");
      return;
   }

   instance = this;
}
#endregion

public void GameOver()
{
   score = 0;
   scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Score: " + gm.score;
}
```

Then you can call theese variables from everywhere and change them as well:

```
GameManager gm;

void Start()
{
   gm = GameManager.instance;
}

void Update()
{
   if (time >= 0)
      gm.GameOver();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216805/discussion-on-answer-by-mathewhd-unity-how-to-reset-score-after-scene-change).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the

```
void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
```

method in your gameover scene to reset theScore variable in your GameObject that holds the variable, if the GameOver scene using a GameEngineObject of some kind.

[Unity Doc SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html)